# How do I Target an individual Bar in Sencha Touch Bar Charts?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have a chart in Sencha Architect and I'd like to be able to Click on an individual Bar and change it's value e.g. +1

How do I go about targeting a specific bar in the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that you can use the Style config within Sencha Architect to change bar colors but you must delete the default Colors in the Colors config first, otherwise Style is ignored.

The Colors config default is an array e.g. ['red','blue'] etc and you can choose a color with attributes.fill = colors[1] for example.